# How can I apply regexp POSIX class subtraction or equivalent?

Tags: ruby, regex, posix

Trying to do this in ruby but I suppose the question is applicable in any regexp language that handles POSIX classes

Goal: I want to replace all of the characters that match the `[[:space:]]` POSIX class except a `tab`, with a regular single space.

Hoping character class subtraction would work with POSIX classes, I tried this but it doesn't work

```rb
value.gsub!(/[ [[:space:]] - [\t] ]/, ' ')
```

Is there a way to rewrite this so I can match and replace any of the characters found in the `[[:space:]]` class except the tab with a single regular space character?

**Update**

Thanks for all of the answers.

The answer I was searching for and defined in my question focused on `[[:space:]]` POSIX class because this class extends beyond just ascii characters and control characters and includes irregular or otherwise non-ascii whitespace equivalents in unicode, etc. Therefore, while I agree I could go and build my own class and find each and every possible whitespace, I'd rather make use of the existing class defined to include those and remove what I want from it.

Initial testing shows that these 3 below answers provided:

```
value.gsub!(/(?!\t)[[:space:]]/, ' ')  # appears to be language agnostic regexp approach which is good if needed

value.gsub!(/[[:space:]&&[^\t]]/, ' ') # for languages that don't actually support true class subtraction 

value.gsub!(/[^[:^space:]\t]/, ' ') # inverse or double negative approach
```

produce the desired results. I like the first two best, but since I originally framed the question with ruby and the answer points out that ruby doesn't actually support class subtraction but instead demonstrates an intersection with a negative, I am choosing that answer for this question because it seems this is good to know even with non-POSIX classes.

Comment: Why not just write your own class? `[\r\n\v\f]`

Comment: `"foo \t bar baz".gsub(/[^\S\t]/, '')` did the trick

Comment: Wrong trick. Trick needs to include all possible matches for [[:space:]], including full width character (i.e. Japanese etc) spaces, and other incarnations of non printable characters.

Comment: Have you tried using a negative lookahead? Try `(?!\t)[[:space:]]`

Comment: Hmm, not yet. I’ll try it when I return to computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
/[[:space:]&&[^\t]]/
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/HDHpuprJrv)

**Details**

- `[` - start of a character class (bracket expression)

  - `[:space:]`  - a POSIX character class matching whitespace chars
  - `&&` - a character class intersection operator
  - `[^\t]` - any char other than a tab
- `]` - end of a character class (bracket expression).

See more about how to use [character class subtraction in Ruby](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html#subtraction).

Comment: I am curious if you have a similar way to do this subtraction (or subtraction by intersection with a negated) when using `tr` or `sed`? My initial testing using `tr` didn't seem to produce correct results. I need to build a counterpart to the ruby solution that uses unix system tools outside of ruby environment (to speed it up when processing large files).

Comment: @Streamline Ruby uses Onigmo regex library, and it is not POSIX, it is an NFA regex library. The only POSIX thing in your current question is the POSIX character class, a `[:<name>:]` construct. POSIX regex engines like `sed` has no character class subtraction feature. Well, not sure if POSIX character classes there are Unicode aware. You might try to combine a negated brackets expression with the POSIX character class and add excluded char there, something like `[^\t[:graph:]]` - any char that is not a printable character and not a tab. In `sed`, add `-E` option to enable ERE POSIX syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby seems to support perl's negated posix classes (though I'm not seeing it documented :( ), so you can do:

```
/[^[:^space:]\t]/
```

(not a non-space or tab)

Answer (score 2):

Try using a negative lookahead assertion in your regex:

```
value.gsub!(/(?!\t)[[:space:]]/, ' ')
```

The negative lookahead will prevent `[[:space:]]` from matching tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The POSIX `[[:space]]` class is simply shorthand for `[ \t\r\n\v\f]`. Therefore, all you need to do is use that same pattern, except without the `\t`, or the space since that's what you're replacing the match with anyway.

`value.gsub!(/[\r\n\v\f]/, ' ')`

For more info see https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Comment: It includes more than just those, such as full width characters beyond ascii set.